# Building a query with options

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make a query in MySQL.
But the query needs to be made dinamically with options choosen by the user.

The options are *Day*, *Month*, *Year* & *SellerID*.

A user will choose if he want to view the sales history from sellers by, days, months and years.

But, let's say he wants to see all sales on **March, 2012**. He will leave *Day* in blank and receive all sales from March 01 till March 31...

And maybe he leaves the option *Month* in blank, and set *Day=15* and *Year=2012*, he will get the sales history from the whole year 2012, and the 15th day of each month only.

My program needs to build a query that covers exactly what he wanted to view.

The question is:
**Do I really need to use thousands of `IF` on my code? Isn't there a better way to do that?**

```
if( ($day==0) && ($month==0) && ($year>0) ){

    $query.="`date`>='{$year}-01-01' AND `date`<='{$year}-12-31'";

}elseif( ($day==0) && ($month>0) && ($year>0) ){

    $query.="`date`>='{$year}-{$month}-01' AND `date`<='{$year}-{$month}-31'";

}elseif{

etc...
```

Comment: I appreciate you have *some* error checking. However, I encourage you to consider [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: So you are using a drop-down for each parameter?  Not a calendar widget?  Rethinking the UI some might make this easier too.  Sane defaults and a good interface might allow what you want without having to write so much logic on the controller.

Comment: Thanks for pointing SQL Injections Jason, I know its existence, but my system will be used for authorized personnel only, and they won't screw up their own database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could preprocess the values before using them:

```
$year  = $year  > 0 ? (int) $year  : 2012;
$month = $month > 0 ? (int) $month : 1;
$day   = $day   > 0 ? (int) $day   : 1;

$query .= sprintf("`date` BETWEEN '%4d-%2d-%2d' AND '%4d-%2d-%2d'",
    $year, $month, $day,
    $year, $month, 31
);
```

Comment: The `between` function prevent it to handle my 2nd example, but it's way better than `IF`, I'll use it, thanks

Comment: If he leaves `Month` in blank, and set only `Day` and `Year`, he'd get the sales history from the whole year, bot just the desired day of each month. @rid

Comment: @BernaMariano, `BETWEEN x AND y` is similar to `... >= x AND ... <= y`. The `>= / <=` version should work just as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'll use your answer, and in that case, I'll use `IF` to `print` only the desired day... Thanks again

Comment: @BernaMariano, sure, if you need special cases, you can change this logic. The main idea is that you can do this much more easily *before* building the query. Once you're at the query, the values are already populated correctly and you can just go ahead and fill them in.

Answer (score 0):

RESTRICT SORTING ON YEAR, MONTH, DATE format or MONTH, Year Month format or Year Format, means level your sorting in hierarchy and for that You need to handle 3 cases here which would work simply on two WHERE clauses DATE>=DYNAMIC_START_DATE  AND DATE<=DYNAMIC_END_DATE (You can also use BETWEEN here)

- If only Year is given then you should set your start date as 1st jan year and end date as 31st dec year
- If month AND Year is given then you should set your start date as 1st month year and end date as [2830/31] month year
- If only date and month AND Year is given then you should set your start date as date month year and end date as date month year.